# How to change AlertDialog size in the program?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a `AlertDialog` and I'd like to **adjust its size** just to fit to the text length and height. What I do is as follows:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisActivity);
dialog.setMessage(curitem.getTitle());
dialog.show();                                                    

TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
textView.setTextSize(7);
textView.setGravity(1);
```

I can change the text size and font. But I can't adjust `dialog`'s size. How can I make the dialog size just fit to the text length and height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

or any other integer value you want.

Comment: Yes it works. I put (width, height) in integer values.

Answer (score 0):

This code may be help you.in this code you have to some modification (give your height and width what you required).

```
Dialog dialog;
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
 dialog = builder.create();
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 dialog.setTitle("my dialog");


 WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
 wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

 DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
 int width = metrics.widthPixels;
 int height = metrics.heightPixels;

 wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
 wmlp.y =  height/2;   //`y position
 dialog.show();
```